# no space left on /run/user/1000

Tags: filesystem, flatpak

Right now I can't launch any new flatpak applications, apparently because `df` reports

```
tmpfs 1607908 1607908 0 100% /run/user/1000
```

Things like `flatpak run org.libreoffice.LibreOffice` also gives an error message:

```
error: Failed to write file
“/run/user/1000/.flatpak/3091774882/info.6QC311”: write() failed: No space left on device
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I'll obviously try to reboot, but it's been less than 6 hours since I last rebooted!

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include the *full* output of `df`? Generally this sort of error isn't seen unless the root partition is completely full, not just the `tmpfs` mounts 

Comment: I'm afraid I have since rebooted, but since doing so cleared up the problem, it seems unlikely that the root partition (500Gb!) was full -- and I'm pretty sure I would've noticed if it were.

Comment: Feel free to update this question later should there be a repeat 